# What is causing my Laravel application to slow down?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I have an application developed using Laravel 5.2 and Eloquent ORM. The application is connected to a MS SQL Server to read/write to data.

I am running into performance issues where the application **sometime** slows down "the page takes 5+ seconds to respond"

I installed "Clockwork" to try to see what is taking long time to execute. After digging into multiple requests I noticed that some queries that are taking long time to finish .

Here is an example of a query that took about 1600ms to finish. (1600ms include perpetration and network latency.)

```
INSERT into [items] ([control_id], [created_at], [interview_id], [is_default], [item_id], [item_title], [item_type], [reporting_value], [updated_at])
values ('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1105', '1 (Poor)', 'Answer', '1', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1106', '2', 'Answer', '2', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1107', '3', 'Answer', '3', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1108', '4', 'Answer', '4', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1109', '5', 'Answer', '5', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1110', '6', 'Answer', '6', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1111', '7', 'Answer', '7', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1112', '8', 'Answer', '8', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1113', '9', 'Answer', '9', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1114', '10 (Excellent)', 'Answer', '10', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1608', 'Don''t Know', 'Others', '98', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('328', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1708', 'Does not have item/department', 'Answer', '99', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1205', '1 (Poor)', 'Answer', '1', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1206', '2', 'Answer', '2', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1207', '3', 'Answer', '3', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1208', '4', 'Answer', '4', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1209', '5', 'Answer', '5', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1210', '6', 'Answer', '6', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1211', '7', 'Answer', '7', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1212', '8', 'Answer', '8', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1213', '9', 'Answer', '9', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1214', '10 (Excellent)', 'Answer', '10', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1618', 'Don''t Know', 'Others', '98', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('338', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1721', 'Does not have item/department', 'Answer', '99', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1472', '1 (Poor)', 'Answer', '1', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1473', '2', 'Answer', '2', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1474', '3', 'Answer', '3', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1475', '4', 'Answer', '4', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1476', '5', 'Answer', '5', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1477', '6', 'Answer', '6', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1478', '7', 'Answer', '7', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1479', '8', 'Answer', '8', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1480', '9', 'Answer', '9', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1481', '10 (Excellent)', 'Answer', '10', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1648', 'Don''t Know', 'Others', '98', '2016-06-23 23:12:02'), 
('408', '2016-06-23 23:12:02', '6278', 'No', '1733', 'Does not have item/department', 'Answer', '99', '2016-06-23 23:12:02')
```

When I execute this query directly using MS SQL Server Management Studio it finishes in 00:00:00 which tells me that the database server is running fine and there are no delays on the data server side.

Since there are lots of data being inserted I am thinking the PDO is taking long time to prepare the statement which is causing a delay for the simple fact that there are 36 rows being prepared here. But, also the problem could be that PDO takes a while to connect database which is why I see a delay is a query which will delay the entire application.

Here is another simple query that took over 1300ms to return 1 row which was completed in 00:00:01 when executing it in MS SQL Management studio.

```
SELECT * FROM [stext] WHERE [interview_id] = '6278' and [control_id] in ('306') ORDER BY [id] ASC
```

This query does not have much to prepare but still took over 1300ms to complete.

Both the Web server and the data server are on the same network and host. Both are located in the same physical room so there should not be any network issues. I even tried to ping the servers and the ping looks very normal.

How can I tell what is causing my application to slow down? Is it PDO performance issue or is it Eloquent that take long time to prepare the statement?

How can I solve this problem?

for the query above, this is the eloquent code that I use

```
$records = array( array(...), array(...));
Item::insert( $records );
```

Comment: Please also show the Eloquent code where you are inserting these values.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is better not to use the PDO for bulk inserts with hundreds of records. It is slow with large amounts of prepared data.
It is better to create plain queries for this purpose.